# Create Gmail IMAP account on Outlook, buttons to allow access grayed out

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

I am using Outlook 2019 desktop app.  It is very intelligent in that when I add an account to a profile and specify that it is Google, it comes up with the right IMAP ports and protocols.  Google then requests two-factor authentication, so I enter my password and also a 6-digit confirmation code that is texted to me.  At that point, however, I get a prompt to allow Microsoft Apps & Services to access my Google account (image below).  Unfortunately, both the options "Deny" and "Allow" are grayed out.

What are the likely causes?

[image]

Comment: Have you scrolled down to the bottom of that dialog box, eg so it knows you'd read all the "this is what you're granting access to" information? Some dialogs will only activate the buttons on a warning like that once they can reasonably say you've read the warnings by at least viewing all of it.

Comment: Yes, I did scroll to the bottom.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your case is similar to this [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1379877/adding-chrome-account-to-outlook-allow-button-gray), it's suggested that you could try the useful suggestion as Christian Hanse mentioned:

> Fixed it in RegEdit. Yesterday I tried
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\
>
> but really it was
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
>
> Added Outlook.exe with hex value 2af8 and after that Outlook was able to add the Gmail account (after a restart)

Comment: Thanks, Christy, but I cannot use regedit.  I'm guessing that it is a Group Policy.  Therefore, it is likely that there is no solution for my situation.  I appreciate the pointer, though.